# How do I use a react.js button to modify a specific Firestore document?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have written a react.js chat room that creates a new firestore document for every message. Each message has three fields: UID (from google), text, and createdAt. Text and UID are then displayed for every document, sorted by createdAt. I am now attempting to create a like button next to each message and a counter.

I added a `likeCount` field to each message. It is initially 0 and displays next to the text.

This looks like this:

```
function ChatMessage(props) {
  const { text, uid, likeCount } = props.message;

  const messageClass = uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received';
  
  return (<>
    <div className={`message ${messageClass}`}>
      <img src={photoURL || 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/23/abott@adorable.png'} />

      
      <div className = "likeCount">

        <button onClick={something?}className="likeCount">
        
        </button>
      </div>
      <p>{likeCount}</p>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  </>)
}
```

so... how can I make each button add one 'like' to the corresponding document?

Thank you for any help and insight. I am new to react.js!

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
class LikeButton extends React.Component {
state = {
    likes: 0
  };

render() {
    
      return '<button>Likes: {this.state.likes} </button>'
  }
}

addLike = () => {
    let newCount = this.state.likes + 1;
      this.setState({
      likes: newCount
    });
  };
```

However, as you are new to `React.js` I would have a look at this helpful [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage) to guide you with interacting with Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your like count from firestore in a lifecycle method, most likely in `componentDidMount` and in `componentDidUpdate`. You can pass down a method for updating likes to the `ChatMessage` functional component from the parent component. Your button in the chat message component would look like this:
`<button onClick={props.addLike} className="likeCount">`
and an example of what your parent component could look like:

```
constructor(props) {
     this.state = {
           chatMessages: []
     }
}

async componentDidMount() {
    const chatMessages = (await chatMessages.get()).data();
    this.setState({ chatMessages });
}

addLike(doc) {
      doc.update({likeCount: doc.likeCount + 1});
}

render() {
     return (
         this.state.chatMessages.map((chatMessage) => {
              return (
                 <ChatMessage 
                      chatMessage={chatMessage} 
                      addLike={this.addLike}
                 />
              )
          }
      )
}
```

Keep in mind this is similar to what you would do, not exactly. Consider this pseudocode.